# ASP.net return View with data variables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("test", new {a = 1, b = 2});
}
```

and my view:

```
<%= a; %>
```

I get an error:

> 'a' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: dont put semicolon ( ; ) after a in the view. and it should be Model.a as below.

`<%= Model.a %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite near the solution! just add model to access its property as bellow

```
  //in your view      
  <%= Model.a %>
```

But I would like to advice to avoid anonymous type in your controller `return View(new{a=foo,b=bar})` is not a good idea.
Please follow these steps

- Create a model

  ```
  namespace ModelCentral{
  public class AbModel
  {
    public int a{get;set;};
    public int b{get;set;};
  }
  }
  ```
- then edit your controller action as this

  ```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
   var model = new AbModel() {a = 1, b = 2};
     return View("test",model);
  }
  ```
- finally in your view

  ```
   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ModelCentral.AbModel>" %>

   <%= Model.a%>
  ```

Comment: if I put model, then I get this error; Character is not valid.

Comment: you need to remove the `;`

Comment: I get an error: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: you are missing the import directive! see my last edits plz

Comment: The directive 'control' is unknown.

Comment: which version of VStudio are u using? are u on mvc3 or mvc5?

Comment: mvc3, visual studio 2013

Comment: See the complete example in my edited answer...Good luck!

Comment: also what should be the masterPageFile?:)

Comment: sample Site.Master `<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
<body>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>`